# Difference between a bundle and a content type

Tags: entities

Can somebody explain to me the difference between a content type and a bundle? Is the latter just a bundle for the entity node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Bundle* is a generic term that applies to every entity Drupal or third-party modules define; *content type* is a specific term that applies to nodes.
Since nodes and content types were introduced a way before Drupal 7, *content type* was the first concept introduced, which then got expanded into the *bundle* concept when entities were introduced in Drupal 7.

So, yes, a content type is a bundle for the *Node* entity.

Answer (score 0):

A content type is just a bundle of the node entity.

Comment: Erm..what? It seems to me that a content type is an instance of a node for a particular type of content (ah ha!). In Drupal 7, entities were introduced (of which nodes are one species of entity) and entities have bundles. So a node entity has a bundle, which is called a content type. So a content type is a bundle of the node entity (ahh, now I get what you wrote!) ;)

Comment: kind of confusing ;)